# Code Composer Studio MSP430 Unresolved Symbols LoRa LMIC

Tags: c++, c, msp430, code-composer

I am getting unresolved symbols with the invocation of the [LoRa lmic Lib function](https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic).

```
LMIC_setTxData2(1, mydata, sizeof(mydata)-1, 0);
```

These are the error messages:

> undefined    |       first referenced       symbol         |
> in file
> onEvent      ./lmic/lmic/lmic.obj
>
> os_getArtEui ./lmic/lmic/lmic.obj
>
> os_getDevEui ./lmic/lmic/lmic.obj
>
> os_getDevKey ./lmic/lmic/lmic.obj

Does anyone have experience with this issue? Thanks.